# Can I create new user in windows7 that is extending all app data and settings from current admin user?

Tags: windows-7

Can I create new user in windows7 that is extending all app data and settings from current admin user?

Comment: You question lacks clarity

Comment: so you want the new non-admin user to have the same access to applications, the same desktop layout, the same documents in the `my documents` folder, etc? Only difference being the name and UAC privileges? Note that some applications my not work anymore without admininistrator rights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manual method :

- Create new user ( "net user cloneuser clonepwd /add" from elevated prompt or use the control panel / users )
- Copy all files from C:\Users\OriginalUser to C:\Users\CloneUser without

  Ntuser.dat

  Ntuser.dat.log

  Ntuser.ini
- Log on as the new user. / There will be things that must be corrected manually for some software /